# Как определить браузер и ip пользователя?

Tags: php

С помощью какого кода можно определить ip и браузер пользователя?

Answer (score 18):

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

IP и клиент, соответственно

Comment: Только от прокси и одиссеем не поможет) Но речь не об этом, просто к слову. А еще лучше сделать <pre>var_dump(`$_SERVER`);</pre> и посмотреть, что там. На некоторых хостингах при некоторых .htaccess имена другие - вроде HTTP_FORWARDED_че-то-там.

Comment: Просто никогда не думал об этом, всегда хватало функционала REMOTE_ADDR. Даже в расширении к опере именно это писал. Спасибо, буду знать

Answer (score 16):

На ваш вопрос в интернете видел ответ... до сих пор пользуюсь данным способом

```
function get_ip()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Comment: Это касается IP пользователя

Comment: Не используйте данный скрипт. Он содержит потенциальную угрозу безопасности. В `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']` и `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` может содержаться инъекция, т.к. эти значения могут быть выставлены на стороне клиента.

Answer (score 13):

Определить IP адрес клиента, от которого пришел запрос, можно только одним единственным способом: `$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` Все остальное к IP адресу не имеет никакого отношения.

Все значения массива `$_SERVER`, начинающиеся на `'HTTP_'`, являются заголовками запроса, которые клиент формирует полностью сам, как ему заблагорассудится.

Comment: Если пользователь использует прокси, то в $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; будет ip прокси, а реальный ip пользователя (если прокси разрешает видеть) будет в $_SERVER['X_FORWARDED_FOR']

Comment: Если пользователь использует прокси, то клиентом для сервера будет являться именно этот прокси.

Еще раз повторюсь. `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` - это обычный заголовок, который клиент формирует сам. Он может записать туда все что угодно, от loopback'а до SQL-инъекции. По этому, если этот proxy-server не ваш, то использовать эти (да и любые другие, типа Client-Ip) заголовки для определения IP ни в коем случае нельзя.

Единственная достоверная информация об IP клиента - это REMOTE_ADDR.

Answer (score 9):

```
class Browser {
    private $_agent = '';
    private $_browser_name = '';
    private $_version = '';
    private $_platform = '';
    private $_os = '';
    private $_is_aol = false;
    private $_is_mobile = false;
    private $_is_robot = false;
    private $_aol_version = '';

    const BROWSER_UNKNOWN = 'unknown';
    const VERSION_UNKNOWN = 'unknown';

    const BROWSER_OPERA = 'Opera';                            // http://www.opera.com/
    const BROWSER_OPERA_MINI = 'Opera Mini';                  // http://www.opera.com/mini/
    const BROWSER_WEBTV = 'WebTV';                            // http://www.webtv.net/pc/
    const BROWSER_IE = 'Internet Explorer';                   // http://www.microsoft.com/ie/
    const BROWSER_POCKET_IE = 'Pocket Internet Explorer';     // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Mobile
    const BROWSER_KONQUEROR = 'Konqueror';                    // http://www.konqueror.org/
    const BROWSER_ICAB = 'iCab';                              // http://www.icab.de/
    const BROWSER_OMNIWEB = 'OmniWeb';                        // http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omniweb/
    const BROWSER_FIREBIRD = 'Firebird';                      // http://www.ibphoenix.com/
    const BROWSER_FIREFOX = 'Firefox';                        // http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/firefox.html
    const BROWSER_ICEWEASEL = 'Iceweasel';                    // http://www.geticeweasel.org/
    const BROWSER_SHIRETOKO = 'Shiretoko';                    // http://wiki.mozilla.org/Projects/shiretoko
    const BROWSER_MOZILLA = 'Mozilla';                        // http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/
    const BROWSER_AMAYA = 'Amaya';                            // http://www.w3.org/Amaya/
    const BROWSER_LYNX = 'Lynx';                              // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx
    const BROWSER_SAFARI = 'Safari';                          // http://apple.com
    const BROWSER_IPHONE = 'iPhone';                          // http://apple.com
    const BROWSER_IPOD = 'iPod';                              // http://apple.com
    const BROWSER_IPAD = 'iPad';                              // http://apple.com
    const BROWSER_CHROME = 'Chrome';                          // http://www.google.com/chrome
    const BROWSER_ANDROID = 'Android';                        // http://www.android.com/
    const BROWSER_GOOGLEBOT = 'GoogleBot';                    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googlebot
    const BROWSER_SLURP = 'Yahoo! Slurp';                     // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Slurp
    const BROWSER_W3CVALIDATOR = 'W3C Validator';             // http://validator.w3.org/
    const BROWSER_BLACKBERRY = 'BlackBerry';                  // http://www.blackberry.com/
    const BROWSER_ICECAT = 'IceCat';                          // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_IceCat
    const BROWSER_NOKIA_S60 = 'Nokia S60 OSS Browser';        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Browser_for_S60
    const BROWSER_NOKIA = 'Nokia Browser';                    // * all other WAP-based browsers on the Nokia Platform
    const BROWSER_MSN = 'MSN Browser';                        // http://explorer.msn.com/
    const BROWSER_MSNBOT = 'MSN Bot';                         // http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm
                                                              // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Msnbot  (used for Bing as well)

    const BROWSER_NETSCAPE_NAVIGATOR = 'Netscape Navigator';  // http://browser.netscape.com/ (DEPRECATED)
    const BROWSER_GALEON = 'Galeon';                          // http://galeon.sourceforge.net/ (DEPRECATED)
    const BROWSER_NETPOSITIVE = 'NetPositive';                // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetPositive (DEPRECATED)
    const BROWSER_PHOENIX = 'Phoenix';                        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Mozilla_Firefox (DEPRECATED)

    const PLATFORM_UNKNOWN = 'unknown';
    const PLATFORM_WINDOWS = 'Windows';
    const PLATFORM_WINDOWS_CE = 'Windows CE';
    const PLATFORM_APPLE = 'Apple';
    const PLATFORM_LINUX = 'Linux';
    const PLATFORM_OS2 = 'OS/2';
    const PLATFORM_BEOS = 'BeOS';
    const PLATFORM_IPHONE = 'iPhone';
    const PLATFORM_IPOD = 'iPod';
    const PLATFORM_IPAD = 'iPad';
    const PLATFORM_BLACKBERRY = 'BlackBerry';
    const PLATFORM_NOKIA = 'Nokia';
    const PLATFORM_FREEBSD = 'FreeBSD';
    const PLATFORM_OPENBSD = 'OpenBSD';
    const PLATFORM_NETBSD = 'NetBSD';
    const PLATFORM_SUNOS = 'SunOS';
    const PLATFORM_OPENSOLARIS = 'OpenSolaris';
    const PLATFORM_ANDROID = 'Android';

    const OPERATING_SYSTEM_UNKNOWN = 'unknown';

    public function Browser($useragent="") {
        $this->reset();
        if( $useragent != "" ) {
            $this->setUserAgent($useragent);
        }
        else {
            $this->determine();
        }
    }

    /**
    * Reset all properties
    */
    public function reset() {
        $this->_agent = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : "";
        $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_UNKNOWN;
        $this->_version = self::VERSION_UNKNOWN;
        $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_UNKNOWN;
        $this->_os = self::OPERATING_SYSTEM_UNKNOWN;
        $this->_is_aol = false;
        $this->_is_mobile = false;
        $this->_is_robot = false;
        $this->_aol_version = self::VERSION_UNKNOWN;
    }

    /**
    * Check to see if the specific browser is valid
    * @param string $browserName
    * @return True if the browser is the specified browser
    */
    function isBrowser($browserName) { return( 0 == strcasecmp($this->_browser_name, trim($browserName))); }

    /**
    * The name of the browser.  All return types are from the class contants
    * @return string Name of the browser
    */
    public function getBrowser() { return $this->_browser_name; }
    /**
    * Set the name of the browser
    * @param $browser The name of the Browser
    */
    public function setBrowser($browser) { return $this->_browser_name = $browser; }
    /**
    * The name of the platform.  All return types are from the class contants
    * @return string Name of the browser
    */
    public function getPlatform() { return $this->_platform; }
    /**
    * Set the name of the platform
    * @param $platform The name of the Platform
    */
    public function setPlatform($platform) { return $this->_platform = $platform; }
    /**
    * The version of the browser.
    * @return string Version of the browser (will only contain alpha-numeric characters and a period)
    */
    public function getVersion() { return $this->_version; }
    /**
    * Set the version of the browser
    * @param $version The version of the Browser
    */
    public function setVersion($version) { $this->_version = preg_replace('/[^0-9,.,a-z,A-Z-]/','',$version); }
    /**
    * The version of AOL.
    * @return string Version of AOL (will only contain alpha-numeric characters and a period)
    */
    public function getAolVersion() { return $this->_aol_version; }
    /**
    * Set the version of AOL
    * @param $version The version of AOL
    */
    public function setAolVersion($version) { $this->_aol_version = preg_replace('/[^0-9,.,a-z,A-Z]/','',$version); }
    /**
    * Is the browser from AOL?
    * @return boolean True if the browser is from AOL otherwise false
    */
    public function isAol() { return $this->_is_aol; }
    /**
    * Is the browser from a mobile device?
    * @return boolean True if the browser is from a mobile device otherwise false
    */
    public function isMobile() { return $this->_is_mobile; }
    /**
    * Is the browser from a robot (ex Slurp,GoogleBot)?
    * @return boolean True if the browser is from a robot otherwise false
    */
    public function isRobot() { return $this->_is_robot; }
    /**
    * Set the browser to be from AOL
    * @param $isAol
    */
    public function setAol($isAol) { $this->_is_aol = $isAol; }
    /**
     * Set the Browser to be mobile
     * @param boolean $value is the browser a mobile brower or not
     */
    protected function setMobile($value=true) { $this->_is_mobile = $value; }
    /**
     * Set the Browser to be a robot
     * @param boolean $value is the browser a robot or not
     */
    protected function setRobot($value=true) { $this->_is_robot = $value; }
    /**
    * Get the user agent value in use to determine the browser
    * @return string The user agent from the HTTP header
    */
    public function getUserAgent() { return $this->_agent; }
    /**
    * Set the user agent value (the construction will use the HTTP header value - this will overwrite it)
    * @param $agent_string The value for the User Agent
    */
    public function setUserAgent($agent_string) {
        $this->reset();
        $this->_agent = $agent_string;
        $this->determine();
    }
    /**
     * Used to determine if the browser is actually "chromeframe"
     * @since 1.7
     * @return boolean True if the browser is using chromeframe
     */
    public function isChromeFrame() {
        return( strpos($this->_agent,"chromeframe") !== false );
    }
    /**
    * Returns a formatted string with a summary of the details of the browser.
    * @return string formatted string with a summary of the browser
    */
    public function __toString() {
        return "<strong>Browser Name:</strong>{$this->getBrowser()}<br/>\n" .
               "<strong>Browser Version:</strong>{$this->getVersion()}<br/>\n" .
               "<strong>Browser User Agent String:</strong>{$this->getUserAgent()}<br/>\n" .
               "<strong>Platform:</strong>{$this->getPlatform()}<br/>";
    }
    /**
     * Protected routine to calculate and determine what the browser is in use (including platform)
     */
    protected function determine() {
        $this->checkPlatform();
        $this->checkBrowsers();
        $this->checkForAol();
    }
    /**
     * Protected routine to determine the browser type
     * @return boolean True if the browser was detected otherwise false
     */
     protected function checkBrowsers() {
        return (
            // well-known, well-used
            // Special Notes:
            // (1) Opera must be checked before FireFox due to the odd
            //     user agents used in some older versions of Opera
            // (2) WebTV is strapped onto Internet Explorer so we must
            //     check for WebTV before IE
            // (3) (deprecated) Galeon is based on Firefox and needs to be
            //     tested before Firefox is tested
            // (4) OmniWeb is based on Safari so OmniWeb check must occur
            //     before Safari
            // (5) Netscape 9+ is based on Firefox so Netscape checks
            //     before FireFox are necessary
            $this->checkBrowserWebTv() ||
            $this->checkBrowserInternetExplorer() ||
            $this->checkBrowserOpera() ||
            $this->checkBrowserGaleon() ||
            $this->checkBrowserNetscapeNavigator9Plus() ||
            $this->checkBrowserFirefox() ||
            $this->checkBrowserChrome() ||
            $this->checkBrowserOmniWeb() ||

            // common mobile
            $this->checkBrowserAndroid() ||
            $this->checkBrowseriPad() ||
            $this->checkBrowseriPod() ||
            $this->checkBrowseriPhone() ||
            $this->checkBrowserBlackBerry() ||
            $this->checkBrowserNokia() ||

            // common bots
            $this->checkBrowserGoogleBot() ||
            $this->checkBrowserMSNBot() ||
            $this->checkBrowserSlurp() ||

            // WebKit base check (post mobile and others)
            $this->checkBrowserSafari() ||

            // everyone else
            $this->checkBrowserNetPositive() ||
            $this->checkBrowserFirebird() ||
            $this->checkBrowserKonqueror() ||
            $this->checkBrowserIcab() ||
            $this->checkBrowserPhoenix() ||
            $this->checkBrowserAmaya() ||
            $this->checkBrowserLynx() ||
            $this->checkBrowserShiretoko() ||
            $this->checkBrowserIceCat() ||
            $this->checkBrowserW3CValidator() ||
            $this->checkBrowserMozilla() /* Mozilla is such an open standard that you must check it last */
        );
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the user is using a BlackBerry (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is the BlackBerry browser otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserBlackBerry() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'blackberry') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode("/",stristr($this->_agent,"BlackBerry"));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_BLACKBERRY;
            $this->setMobile(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the user is using an AOL User Agent (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is from AOL otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkForAol() {
        $this->setAol(false);
        $this->setAolVersion(self::VERSION_UNKNOWN);

        if( stripos($this->_agent,'aol') !== false ) {
            $aversion = explode(' ',stristr($this->_agent, 'AOL'));
            $this->setAol(true);
            $this->setAolVersion(preg_replace('/[^0-9\.a-z]/i', '', $aversion[1]));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is the GoogleBot or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is the GoogletBot otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserGoogleBot() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'googlebot') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'googlebot'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion(str_replace(';','',$aversion[0]));
            $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_GOOGLEBOT;
            $this->setRobot(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is the MSNBot or not (last updated 1.9)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is the MSNBot otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserMSNBot() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,"msnbot") !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode("/",stristr($this->_agent,"msnbot"));
            $aversion = explode(" ",$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion(str_replace(";","",$aversion[0]));
            $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_MSNBOT;
            $this->setRobot(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is the W3C Validator or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is the W3C Validator otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserW3CValidator() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'W3C-checklink') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'W3C-checklink'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_W3CVALIDATOR;
            return true;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent,'W3C_Validator') !== false ) {
            // Some of the Validator versions do not delineate w/ a slash - add it back in
            $ua = str_replace("W3C_Validator ", "W3C_Validator/", $this->_agent);
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($ua,'W3C_Validator'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_W3CVALIDATOR;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is the Yahoo! Slurp Robot or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is the Yahoo! Slurp Robot otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserSlurp() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'slurp') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Slurp'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_SLURP;
            $this->setRobot(true);
            $this->setMobile(false);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Internet Explorer or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Internet Explorer otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserInternetExplorer() {

        // Test for v1 - v1.5 IE
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'microsoft internet explorer') !== false ) {
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_IE);
            $this->setVersion('1.0');
            $aresult = stristr($this->_agent, '/');
            if( preg_match('/308|425|426|474|0b1/i', $aresult) ) {
                $this->setVersion('1.5');
            }
            return true;
        }
        // Test for versions > 1.5
        else if( stripos($this->_agent,'msie') !== false && stripos($this->_agent,'opera') === false ) {
            // See if the browser is the odd MSN Explorer
            if( stripos($this->_agent,'msnb') !== false ) {
                $aresult = explode(' ',stristr(str_replace(';','; ',$this->_agent),'MSN'));
                $this->setBrowser( self::BROWSER_MSN );
                $this->setVersion(str_replace(array('(',')',';'),'',$aresult[1]));
                return true;
            }
            $aresult = explode(' ',stristr(str_replace(';','; ',$this->_agent),'msie'));
            $this->setBrowser( self::BROWSER_IE );
            $this->setVersion(str_replace(array('(',')',';'),'',$aresult[1]));
            return true;
        }
        // Test for Pocket IE
        else if( stripos($this->_agent,'mspie') !== false || stripos($this->_agent,'pocket') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode(' ',stristr($this->_agent,'mspie'));
            $this->setPlatform( self::PLATFORM_WINDOWS_CE );
            $this->setBrowser( self::BROWSER_POCKET_IE );
            $this->setMobile(true);

            if( stripos($this->_agent,'mspie') !== false ) {
                $this->setVersion($aresult[1]);
            }
            else {
                $aversion = explode('/',$this->_agent);
                $this->setVersion($aversion[1]);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Opera or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Opera otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserOpera() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'opera mini') !== false ) {
            $resultant = stristr($this->_agent, 'opera mini');
            if( preg_match('/\//',$resultant) ) {
                $aresult = explode('/',$resultant);
                $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
                $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            }
            else {
                $aversion = explode(' ',stristr($resultant,'opera mini'));
                $this->setVersion($aversion[1]);
            }
            $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_OPERA_MINI;
            $this->setMobile(true);
            return true;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent,'opera') !== false ) {
            $resultant = stristr($this->_agent, 'opera');
            if( preg_match('/Version\/(10.*)$/',$resultant,$matches) ) {
                $this->setVersion($matches[1]);
            }
            else if( preg_match('/\//',$resultant) ) {
                $aresult = explode('/',str_replace("("," ",$resultant));
                $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
                $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            }
            else {
                $aversion = explode(' ',stristr($resultant,'opera'));
                $this->setVersion(isset($aversion[1])?$aversion[1]:"");
            }
            $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_OPERA;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Chrome or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Chrome otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserChrome() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Chrome') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Chrome'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_CHROME);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is WebTv or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is WebTv otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserWebTv() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'webtv') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'webtv'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_WEBTV);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is NetPositive or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is NetPositive otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserNetPositive() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'NetPositive') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'NetPositive'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion(str_replace(array('(',')',';'),'',$aversion[0]));
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_NETPOSITIVE);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Galeon or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Galeon otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserGaleon() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'galeon') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode(' ',stristr($this->_agent,'galeon'));
            $aversion = explode('/',$aresult[0]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_GALEON);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Konqueror or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Konqueror otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserKonqueror() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Konqueror') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode(' ',stristr($this->_agent,'Konqueror'));
            $aversion = explode('/',$aresult[0]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_KONQUEROR);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is iCab or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is iCab otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserIcab() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'icab') !== false ) {
            $aversion = explode(' ',stristr(str_replace('/',' ',$this->_agent),'icab'));
            $this->setVersion($aversion[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_ICAB);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is OmniWeb or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is OmniWeb otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserOmniWeb() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'omniweb') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'omniweb'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',isset($aresult[1])?$aresult[1]:"");
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_OMNIWEB);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Phoenix or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Phoenix otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserPhoenix() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Phoenix') !== false ) {
            $aversion = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Phoenix'));
            $this->setVersion($aversion[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_PHOENIX);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Firebird or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Firebird otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserFirebird() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Firebird') !== false ) {
            $aversion = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Firebird'));
            $this->setVersion($aversion[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_FIREBIRD);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Netscape Navigator 9+ or not (last updated 1.7)
     * NOTE: (http://browser.netscape.com/ - Official support ended on March 1st, 2008)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Netscape Navigator 9+ otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserNetscapeNavigator9Plus() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Firefox') !== false && preg_match('/Navigator\/([^ ]*)/i',$this->_agent,$matches) ) {
            $this->setVersion($matches[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_NETSCAPE_NAVIGATOR);
            return true;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent,'Firefox') === false && preg_match('/Netscape6?\/([^ ]*)/i',$this->_agent,$matches) ) {
            $this->setVersion($matches[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_NETSCAPE_NAVIGATOR);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Shiretoko or not (https://wiki.mozilla.org/Projects/shiretoko) (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Shiretoko otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserShiretoko() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Mozilla') !== false && preg_match('/Shiretoko\/([^ ]*)/i',$this->_agent,$matches) ) {
            $this->setVersion($matches[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_SHIRETOKO);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Ice Cat or not (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_IceCat) (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Ice Cat otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserIceCat() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Mozilla') !== false && preg_match('/IceCat\/([^ ]*)/i',$this->_agent,$matches) ) {
            $this->setVersion($matches[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_ICECAT);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Nokia or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Nokia otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserNokia() {
        if( preg_match("/Nokia([^\/]+)\/([^ SP]+)/i",$this->_agent,$matches) ) {
            $this->setVersion($matches[2]);
            if( stripos($this->_agent,'Series60') !== false || strpos($this->_agent,'S60') !== false ) {
                $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_NOKIA_S60);
            }
            else {
                $this->setBrowser( self::BROWSER_NOKIA );
            }
            $this->setMobile(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Firefox or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Firefox otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserFirefox() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'safari') === false ) {
            if( preg_match("/Firefox[\/ \(]([^ ;\)]+)/i",$this->_agent,$matches) ) {
                $this->setVersion($matches[1]);
                $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_FIREFOX);
                return true;
            }
            else if( preg_match("/Firefox$/i",$this->_agent,$matches) ) {
                $this->setVersion("");
                $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_FIREFOX);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Firefox or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Firefox otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserIceweasel() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Iceweasel') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Iceweasel'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_ICEWEASEL);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Mozilla or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Mozilla otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserMozilla() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'mozilla') !== false  && preg_match('/rv:[0-9].[0-9][a-b]?/i',$this->_agent) && stripos($this->_agent,'netscape') === false) {
            $aversion = explode(' ',stristr($this->_agent,'rv:'));
            preg_match('/rv:[0-9].[0-9][a-b]?/i',$this->_agent,$aversion);
            $this->setVersion(str_replace('rv:','',$aversion[0]));
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_MOZILLA);
            return true;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent,'mozilla') !== false && preg_match('/rv:[0-9]\.[0-9]/i',$this->_agent) && stripos($this->_agent,'netscape') === false ) {
            $aversion = explode('',stristr($this->_agent,'rv:'));
            $this->setVersion(str_replace('rv:','',$aversion[0]));
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_MOZILLA);
            return true;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent,'mozilla') !== false  && preg_match('/mozilla\/([^ ]*)/i',$this->_agent,$matches) && stripos($this->_agent,'netscape') === false ) {
            $this->setVersion($matches[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_MOZILLA);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Lynx or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Lynx otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserLynx() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'lynx') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Lynx'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',(isset($aresult[1])?$aresult[1]:""));
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_LYNX);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Amaya or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Amaya otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserAmaya() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'amaya') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Amaya'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_AMAYA);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Safari or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Safari otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserSafari() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Safari') !== false && stripos($this->_agent,'iPhone') === false && stripos($this->_agent,'iPod') === false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Version'));
            if( isset($aresult[1]) ) {
                $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
                $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            }
            else {
                $this->setVersion(self::VERSION_UNKNOWN);
            }
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_SAFARI);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is iPhone or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is iPhone otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowseriPhone() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'iPhone') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Version'));
            if( isset($aresult[1]) ) {
                $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
                $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            }
            else {
                $this->setVersion(self::VERSION_UNKNOWN);
            }
            $this->setMobile(true);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_IPHONE);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is iPod or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is iPod otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowseriPad() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'iPad') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Version'));
            if( isset($aresult[1]) ) {
                $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
                $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            }
            else {
                $this->setVersion(self::VERSION_UNKNOWN);
            }
            $this->setMobile(true);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_IPAD);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is iPod or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is iPod otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowseriPod() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'iPod') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Version'));
            if( isset($aresult[1]) ) {
                $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
                $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            }
            else {
                $this->setVersion(self::VERSION_UNKNOWN);
            }
            $this->setMobile(true);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_IPOD);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the browser is Android or not (last updated 1.7)
     * @return boolean True if the browser is Android otherwise false
     */
    protected function checkBrowserAndroid() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Android') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode(' ',stristr($this->_agent,'Android'));
            if( isset($aresult[1]) ) {
                $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
                $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            }
            else {
                $this->setVersion(self::VERSION_UNKNOWN);
            }
            $this->setMobile(true);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_ANDROID);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine the user's platform (last updated 1.7)
     */
    protected function checkPlatform() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent, 'windows') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_WINDOWS;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent, 'iPad') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_IPAD;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent, 'iPod') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_IPOD;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent, 'iPhone') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_IPHONE;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent, 'mac') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_APPLE;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent, 'android') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_ANDROID;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent, 'linux') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_LINUX;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent, 'Nokia') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_NOKIA;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent, 'BlackBerry') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_BLACKBERRY;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent,'FreeBSD') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_FREEBSD;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent,'OpenBSD') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_OPENBSD;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent,'NetBSD') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_NETBSD;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent, 'OpenSolaris') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_OPENSOLARIS;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent, 'SunOS') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_SUNOS;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent, 'OS\/2') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_OS2;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent, 'BeOS') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_BEOS;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent, 'win') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_WINDOWS;
        }

    }
}
```

И это только браузер =))))

Comment: Проще воспользоваться функцией [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/get-browser), не забыв предварительно скачать [browscap.ini](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads)

Comment: то же как возможно.
я привел пример как расширенный вариант.
Вдруг именно Apple кому то понадобится)))

пробовал - работает не плохо.


сам еще пользуюсь для заглушки ИЕ6 


$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
if ( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 6.0') !=false or stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 7.0') != false) {
if (!isset($HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["ie"])) {
setcookie("ie", "yes", time()+60*60*24);
header ("Location: /ie6/ie6.html");
}
}

и редеректую на страницу с предлогом обновить браузер.
думаю что автор как раз для подобных вещей создавал тему.

Comment: @KoVaLsKy, а Вы думаете, что **почти за год** тема (по крайней мере для автора) не потеряла актуальности ?

Comment: И как это ведет себя под нагрузкой?

Comment: ну а кто сказал что нужно все использовать?
посмотрите тут куче регулярно повторяющихся условий.

Вы ж никогда не будите проверять все все браузеры?

можно оставить только необходимое.

Comment: @avp
А Вы действительно думаете что это только ему нужно?
я когда гуглил то же сюда попадал. и ничего не нашел.

Comment: @KoVaLsKy, может кому-нибудь это и надо. В принципе я понимаю, что Вам хочется поделиться с сообществом такой информацией и возможно обсудить что и как лучше использовать.

Вот и открыли бы свою (новую) тему.

Comment: @KoVaLsKy, такую длинную телегу было бы премного эстетичнее залить на [github](https://github.com/) или хотя бы на [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: На мотив послушника тьмы из варкрафта:

We need more lines!

Comment: Слишком много кода.....

Answer (score 6):

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$_SERVER['X_FORWARDED_FOR'] - если прокся, и если вообще разрешает видить реальный ип
```

Answer (score 4):

IP еще можно узнать так:

```
function(){
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)) {
    $IP = array_pop(explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']));
}
return $IP;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Браузер узнаем через

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

А вот, чтобы узнать IP я использую функцию, что очень удобно и универсально.

```
function getRealIP()
{

   if( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] != '' )
   {
      $client_ip =
         ( !empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ) ?
            $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
            :
            ( ( !empty($_ENV['REMOTE_ADDR']) ) ?
               $_ENV['REMOTE_ADDR']
               :
               "unknown" );
      $entries = split('[, ]', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);

      reset($entries);
      while (list(, $entry) = each($entries))
      {
         $entry = trim($entry);
         if ( preg_match("/^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/", $entry, $ip_list) )
         {
            $private_ip = array(
                  '/^0\./',
                  '/^127\.0\.0\.1/',
                  '/^192\.168\..*/',
                  '/^172\.((1[6-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[0-1]))\..*/',
                  '/^10\..*/');

            $found_ip = preg_replace($private_ip, $client_ip, $ip_list[1]);

            if ($client_ip != $found_ip)
            {
               $client_ip = $found_ip;
               break;
            }
         }
      }
   }
   else
   {
      $client_ip =
         ( !empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ) ?
            $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
            :
            ( ( !empty($_ENV['REMOTE_ADDR']) ) ?
               $_ENV['REMOTE_ADDR']
               :
               "unknown" );
   }

   return $client_ip;

}
```

Пример получения IP адреса:

```
$real_ip = getRealIP();
```

Comment: Как-то очень всего ненужного в скрипте... Где вы его раскопали?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.split.php

Answer (score 1):

## Браузер

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

---

## IP

```
$ip = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP', FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)
    ?: filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)
    ?: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    ?? '0.0.0.0'; // или другое значение для "не определён" в вашей логике
```