# Как узнать ip адрес через php?

Tags: php

Как узнать ip адрес через php?

Answer (score 0):

[вот тут смотри](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18507/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8-ip-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F), уже было ;)